# Create Multiple Contacts from Single Request by batching in Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to Create Multiple Contacts from Single Request by batching in Microsoft Graph Api.I am getting the error of Bad Request against [url] (http://prntscr.com/p75ml5) and my end [result](http://prntscr.com/p75n74) & my code is [this] (http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/u3ru-dnqe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint for batch operation is: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch`.

Please modify your endpoint in your code.